# ahtzee Upper Section Scoring

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Description**

The game of Yahtzee is played by rolling five 6-sided dice, and scoring the results in a number of ways. You are given a Yahtzee dice roll, represented as a sorted list of 5 integers, each of which is between 1 and 6 inclusive. Your task is to find the maximum possible score for this roll in the upper section of the Yahtzee score card. Here's what that means.

For the purpose of this challenge, the upper section of Yahtzee gives you six possible ways to score a roll. 1 times the number of 1's in the roll, 2 times the number of 2's, 3 times the number of 3's, and so on up to 6 times the number of 6's. For instance, consider the roll [2, 3, 5, 5, 6]. If you scored this as 1's, the score would be 0, since there are no 1's in the roll. If you scored it as 2's, the score would be 2, since there's one 2 in the roll. Scoring the roll in each of the six ways gives you the six possible scores:

```
0 2 3 0 10 6
```

it has been 3 days i am trying to program it right, but i have a problem in the `elif len() == 1`, when there is for example `[1,1,2,6,4]` it prints out 6 while it has to print 2 (bcs 1 is repeated twice)

```
import random
dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
dice4 = random.randint(1,6)
dice5 = random.randint(1,6)
result = [dice1,dice2,dice3,dice4,dice5]
one_rep = result.count(1)
two_rep = result.count(2)
three_rep = result.count(3)
four_rep = result.count(4)
five_rep = result.count(5)
six_rep = result.count(6)
reps = [one_rep,two_rep,three_rep,four_rep,five_rep,six_rep]
repsnum = [one_rep*1,two_rep*2,three_rep*3,four_rep*4,five_rep*5,six_rep*6]
repeated= []
test = [1]
def yahtzee():
    for x in reps:
        if x > 1:
            repeated.append(x*(reps.index(x)+1))
            s = repeated[0]
    if reps.count(1) == 5:
        score = max(result)
    elif len(repeated) == len(test):
        score = s
    else:
        score = max(repsnum)
    return f'Your result is {dice1},{dice2},{dice3},{dice4},{dice5}\nYour score is {score}'


yahtzee()
print(yahtzee())
```

i have found the solution and here is the code:

```
import random
def yahtzee(result = [random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6),random.randint(1,6)]):
    reps = [result.count(1),result.count(2),result.count(3),result.count(4),result.count(5),result.count(6)]
    repsnum = [result.count(1)*1,result.count(2)*2,result.count(3)*3,result.count(4)*4,result.count(5)*5,result.count(6)*6]
    repeated= []
    for x in reps:
        if x > 1:
            repeated.append(x)
    if reps.count(1) == 5:
        score = max(result)
    elif len(repeated) == 1:
        score = repeated[0]*(reps.index(repeated[0])+1)
    else:
        score = max(repsnum)
    return f'Your result is {result[0]},{result[1]},{result[2]},{result[3]},{result[4]}\nYour score is {score}'

print(yahtzee())
```

Comment: So .... you say you have a problem where `elif len() == 1`, but I don't see that in the posted code.  Seems you may have updated the code.  Can you update the question to match?

Comment: when i run the code it doesn't work, if the len(repeated) == 1 it doesnt return score = s at all

Comment: okay i corrected it and now it works (y).